# Why declaring a variable in a .h file will allocate memory for each .c file includes it, Is it ANSI C?

Tags: c, compilation, ansi-c

Assume I have a `file.h` and in it I have:

```
int arr[128];
(void)(*func_ptr)(int);
```

And I have `code1.c`, `code2.c`, `code3.c` includes it. Will `arr` and `func_ptr` will be global scope allocated for each .c file ? i.e. each .c file will have his own instance of `arr` and `func_ptr`? if so why is that ?

does using `static` can change the result ? what is the ANSI c rule?

Comment: Why all the downvotes to the question and answers ????

Comment: I also wondered about this. Sometimes I have the impression that people are downvoting just for the fun of it. :( I updated my answer to include your static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will arr and func_ptr will be global scope allocated for each .c file ?

Yes it will, and you will end up with a linking error since you have defined the same variable names several places at global scope.

Header files you #include in your .c files are just inserted into your .c file, there's nothing special about them. It works just as you concatenated all the header files your .c file includes, and then compile the result.

In that respect, the net result is exactly as if you wrote `int arr[128];` in each of your .c file

Comment: Cool so I just have to put `static int arr[128]` and each file will have its own `arr`.

Answer (score 2):

This will not compile because the variable `arr` is a global scope and you will get a linker error with a duplicate symbol.

If you declare it static, then it would be allocated in each sourcefile with a separate memory, but then it would be only accessible within that sourcefile or via pointer explicitly returned to a different file.

If you want to access the same block of memory in each sourcefile, you have to declare it in one file as above, and in all other files with `extern` prepended.

The same is for `func_ptr`

**Update**

If you add `static` to the definition, then the scope is local wherever you defined it. If you define a global static variable it will be visible only in that module. If you define a static variable in a function, it will be visible only in that function, so you can have the same name in multiple functions without interfering.

```
foo1()
{
     static int i;
}

foo2()
{
     static int i;
}
```

This would compile fine, because it acts similar like a namespace.

Comment: Just to check, if OP declares it in the header file, and defines it only once, won't that be okay? I just tried this out with several source files including the same header but only one defining the function and then I called it in `main`. It worked fine (of course it's another story why someone would include a header which s/he's not going to use).

Comment: ya function definitions will not be copied!! Only variables and pointers will be duplicated.

Comment: If you declare it in the include file, and include it in multiple source files, th declaration is in all files. That's why you have to use the `extern` keyword. Maybe you did something else? Have to look at your code to see if there is a difference. this should definitely not link, though it would compile. The above sample is a variable to a function, not just a declaration.

Comment: I had a `header.h` file where I declare the function, then two source files `file1.c` and `file2.c` and a `main.c`. I defined it only in `file1.c` but included `header.h` in all three `*.c` files and I called it only in `main.c`. Let me see if I can store this on a link or something.

Comment: @Devolus
Something like - http://codebin.org/view/d657bd00
Regarding the downvote, no idea, I was only enquirinng :)

Comment: @Nobilis, declaring a function is something different than defining a variable. A function declaration is just there to tell the signature of a function and doesn't reserve any space for it. it doesnt even guarantee that the function exists at all. As I said, your example is a prototype declaration and not a variable.

Comment: @Devolus yes, I wanted to check that, all cool then, thanks (+1) :)

Comment: Devolus, I want it to be allocated for each .c file separately. That is the all point of the question

Comment: If you compile ti strictly as C, it works as described above. Jens was right about that, as this is a differnce between C and C++. I tested it with gcc as a strict C sample and this compiles without any errors.